# Set directive scope value based on ng-repeat $index

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat for multiple child directives. On the first instance of the child directive, I want to set the attribute 'doAutofocus' to true.  When I try my code below, I get a parsing error.

> Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error

My directive 'tradePanel', has a scope of `{trade: '=', doAutofocus: '='}`

When my ng-repeat `$index == 0`, I want the doAutofocus to be true, else false.

I use blade templates on the server side which use `{{ }}`.

For angularjs templates, I am using:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{%');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%}');
```

How do I get my doAutofocus attribute set correctly for my first instance?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="trade in deal.trades">
    <trade-panel trade="deal.trades[$index]" ng-attr-do-autofocus="{% ( $index === 0 ) ? true : false %}"></trade-panel>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show more information about the error? Also, where are you configuring the $interpolateProvider? Is this being done in a config block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using two-way binding for your `doAutofocus` directive scope attribute, you cannot use interpolation here. Simply write the expression you wish to pass to the directive. This has to be an existing value on the parent scope. Since we are inside `ng-repeat` block you can just use the provided `$first` variable:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="trade in deal.trades">
  <trade-panel trade="trade" do-autofocus="$first"></trade-panel>
</div>
```